# Does Lync support recording Instant Messages

Tags: lync

I feel stupid for having to ask this, but I can't seem to find it.

I used to use Lotus Notes, which allowed me to record an IM chats I wanted, but it seems Lync only allows phone conversations to be recorded.  Is there the option in Lync to record that IM chats?  I'm assuming if I can record a phone call, I can records IMs.

Thanks

Comment: I thought lync stores chat history when you double click the contact

Comment: If I double click on the name in a conversation, it just bring up their business card.

Comment: Check your outlook. It should have a folder "Conversation History".

Comment: I do, but always empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the conversations. Just select the "Options" icon, then "Personal" from the list on the left. Select the option "Save instant message conversations in my email Conversation History folder".

We use Outlook, and there is a Conversation History folder listed with the other standard folders. Different email clients may integrate differently.

Comment: D'oh!  just noticed that option.  I was ignoring it before cause it was greyed out (guess the SAs don't want us using that feature).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that conversation history of Microsoft Lync is by default integrated with Outlook.

Look at Tools -> Options -> Personal -> check box labeled `Save IM conversations in my email Conversation History folder`.

Hope it helps.